# exit from STDIN from bash script when the user want to close it

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, stdin

I'm automating the file creation from a bash script. I generated a file `rc_notes.txt` which has commit messages from two tags and want to re-write that in a new file as `rc_device.txt`.

**I want the user to write the customer release notes and exit from the BASH** `STDIN` that I prompt in the terminal.

**The problem in my script is I'm not able to trap the close of file.**

Wondering how to do. I don't want to trap the close signal. I want to enter magic string example:  `Done` or some string that triggers the closure of STDIN, that exit from the script gracefully.

---

**My script:**

```
#/bin/bash

set -e


echo "Creating the release candiate text"
rc_file=rc_updater_notes.txt
echo "=========Reading the released commit message file=========="
cat $rc_file
echo "=========End of the commit message file=========="

echo "Now write the release notes"

#exec  < /dev/tty
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" > rc_file.txt
```

It does create the file but I need to exit manually by entering `ctrl+D` or `ctrl+z`. I don't want to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: how the user closes stdin ctrl+C or ctrl+D ?

Comment: I want the user to enter a string as "Done". I want to catch this string want to close STDIN or exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break the loop when "Done" is entered

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = Done ]]; then
        break;
    fi
    echo "$line"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" > rc_file.txt
```

or

```
while read line && [[ $line != Done ]]
do
    echo "$line"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}" > rc_file.txt
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I don't want to trap the signal. Thanks.