# Bash script won't exit on input command

Tags: bash, git, npm, post-commit-hook

I have a bash script that runs on git post-commit hook. What it does is asking the user for an input and based on input it will trigger another action and exits.

The problem is that it will not exit when the action is run, meaning when for example 0 is inputed `npm version patch` runs and finished but the script hangs there. Have to manual close it using `ctrl+c` to exit script.

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "
Script app versioning started! 
"

exec < /dev/tty

while true; do   
read -p "What version should the project update to? 
    - patch[x.x.1] press 0
    - minor[x.1.x] press 1  
    - major[1.x.x] press 2
    - skip patching press 3
    " answer
    case $answer in
            [0] ) 
            npm version patch ;
            exit 0;;
            [1] ) npm version minor;
            exit 0;;
            [2] ) npm version major;
            exit 0;; 
            [3] ) echo "No version patched";
            exit 0;;
            * ) echo "Please answer 0, 1 or 2.";;
    esac
done

echo "
Script app versioning ended!
"
exit 0
```

is it due to the redirect from command `exec < /dev/tty` that for when 0,1 or 2 is inputed and the `npm version patch` command will break output, so it will just continue without `exit 0` been triggered and just hangs?
If so how do i fix that? tried to redirect the output back like `exec > /dev/tty` but not working.

Removing the `exec < /dev/tty` will run the script and exit but won't wait for my command input.

Comment: `#/bin/sh` --> should be `#!/bin/sh`..seems to be a typo!

Comment: Not sure if the commit hook has access to a tty terminal at all. Anyway, you could implement your menu with the `select`. Example: `select a in 'foo' 'bar' 'baz'; do echo "$a"; break; done`

Comment: thanks, corrected it. but still not fixing the problem.

Comment: @LéaGris thank you, I will try your suggestion and come back with an answer :)

Comment: the `read -p` is a bash only option. You need to adjust your shebang to bash and make sure the script is run with bash within the hook.

Comment: @LéaGris actually your version will work in a way, but helped me detect something else. If i run the script without `exec < /dev/tty ` the script just runs wihtout letting me input any command. Same as in your select example.

Comment: Why is `exec < /dev/tty` there in the first place? I've never seen that in a script.

Comment: Could you try press ctrl-d at the end? It should close input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869760/exit-from-stdin-from-bash-script-when-the-user-want-to-close-it

Comment: @kan yes that's the issue i hav to ctrl+d or ctrl+z. I tried your answer but to no avail... The script runs ok if i run it from on it's own, but not from the git post-commit hook. I reckon its somethign with how git outputs after doing it's npm version ?

Comment: @l0b0 to capture my input and wait for the while read. If i do not put that into the script whe nrunning via the post -commit hook it will just run thru the script without waiting for my input so making it usless... is there nay other way to do make the script wait for my input without that command? I'm not a  good with bash scripts and I'm just learning

Comment: @kan if  you could please also explain what does  done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"  do in your example? it redirects the stdin out back? if so shouldn't it be  < "${1:-/dev/tty}" in my case? or i got it wrong ...

Comment: guys i made it work. I've added `done  < "${1:-/dev/stdout}" ` on the last line and now my scripts exit even in git hook. Thank you all for you're help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix my script by redirecting back my stdout like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "
Script app versioning started! 
"

exec < /dev/tty

while true; do   
read -p "What version should the project update to? 
    - patch[x.x.1] press 0
    - minor[x.1.x] press 1  
    - major[1.x.x] press 2
    - skip patching press 3
    " answer
    case $answer in
            [0] ) 
            npm version patch ;
            exit 0;;
            [1] ) npm version minor;
            exit 0;;
            [2] ) npm version major;
            exit 0;; 
            [3] ) echo "No version patched";
            exit 0;;
            * ) echo "Please answer 0, 1 or 2.";;
    esac
done  < "${1:-/dev/stdout}"
```